# Finding values of $a, b$ such that $0\le x^4 +x^3 +ax+b\le (x^2-1)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Given real values of $a, b$ such that for all $x\ge0$,
$$0\le x^5+x^3+ax+b\le (x^2-1)^2\ ,$$
find the value of $ab$.

What I've done is let $x=1$, thus $$0\le2+a+b\le0$$ this forces $a+b=-2$.
let $x=0$, $0\le b\le 1$.
I'm stuck here please help thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your right hand inequality simplifies to
$$x^5-x^4+x^3+2x^2+ax+b-1\le0$$
and it is impossible for this to hold for all $x\ge0$.  So the problem has no solution.

Comment: sorry the problem is edited to X^5

Comment: Still not possible since for large positive $x$ , $x^5>x^4$